# Numbering and creating dataframes in a groupby loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a function which will split a dataframe "df" into smaller dataframes df1, df2...dfn such that all records with the same ID (from column "UNIT-ID") are grouped together and stored in those smaller dataframes, in the folder respectively. **I want them named as df1,df2..dfn**

```
for i, g in df.groupby('ORISPL-UNIT'):
     df['df' + **<loops to number the dataframes>** ] = g
```

I am looking to name the dataframes by the numbers 1,2,3..n after df. How can I do that in the loop?I want dataframes created inside the loop when the groups are getting formed by the groupby function.

I had asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53270894/splitting-and-extracting-dataframes-by-categories-in-a-column-python) yesterday but it was marked duplicate by a fellow member. I am trying to be more specific of what I want to do with my problem exactly in this question

```
Input:

UNIT-ID Q1  Q2  Q3
110-P1  37  487 0
110-P1  31  140 1
110-P1  46  214 1
110-P2  29  287 1
110-P2  45  131 1
110-P2  39  260 0
110-P5  13  413 1
110-P5  13  259 1
110-P5  16  226 1
110-P5  49  456 1
110-P5  39  275 1
110-P10 41  189 0
110-P10 32  269 0
110-P10 31  123 1
110-P10 32  487 0
110-P10 24  398 0
110-15  23  346 0
110-15  31  419 1
110-15  37  287 0
110-15  36  228 1
110-15  48  309 1

Output:
df1:        
 UNIT-ID    Q1  Q2  Q3
    110-P1  37  487 0
    110-P1  31  140 1
    110-P1  46  214 1

df2:            
 UNIT-ID    Q1  Q2  Q3
    110-P2  29  287 1
    110-P2  45  131 1
    110-P2  39  260 0

df3:        
 UNIT-ID    Q1  Q2  Q3
    110-P5  13  413 1
    110-P5  13  259 1
    110-P5  16  226 1
    110-P5  49  456 1
    110-P5  39  275 1

df4:        
 UNIT-ID    Q1  Q2  Q3
    110-P10 41  189 0
    110-P10 32  269 0
    110-P10 31  123 1
    110-P10 32  487 0
    110-P10 24  398 0

df5:        
 UNIT-ID    Q1  Q2  Q3
    110-15  23  346 0
    110-15  31  419 1
    110-15  37  287 0
    110-15  36  228 1
    110-15  48  309 1
    110-15  34  390 1
    110-15  67  238 1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Essentially, I am looking to access each group in the groupby df and store it as df1, df2, df3.. dfn; where n = number of groups in the original df

Comment: Do not save many separate data frames to flood global environment. Use a container like `list` or `dict`.

Comment: You lose no functionality of the data frame when using a list or dict. These containers simply help organize and reference similar objects and can easily run same methods on all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `locals` can do the job by not recommend , you can using `dict` to store the dataframe

```
variables = locals()
for i,j in enumerate(df.groupby('UNIT-ID')):
    variables["df{0}".format(i+1)] = j[1]
df1
Out[13]: 
   UNIT-ID  Q1   Q2  Q3
16  110-15  23  346   0
17  110-15  31  419   1
18  110-15  37  287   0
19  110-15  36  228   1
20  110-15  48  309   1
```

---

Using dict

```
d={"df{0}".format(i+1):j[1]for i,j in enumerate(df.groupby('UNIT-ID'))}
d['df1']
Out[17]: 
   UNIT-ID  Q1   Q2  Q3
16  110-15  23  346   0
17  110-15  31  419   1
18  110-15  37  287   0
19  110-15  36  228   1
20  110-15  48  309   1
```

Comment: To OP and future readers: importantly, use python's `enumerate()` for iterator count.

Comment: @W-B, thanks, enumerate works perfectly for my example. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Parfait, thanks for your suggestive notes. I am looking to use each of the newly created and split dataframes to individually use to train a neural network. Is it possible  to use a list/ dict and still be able to do that?

Comment: Using the "locals", I have all the dataframes separate - df1, df2 ... dfn. Now I want to run a DL model over each of these individual dataframes, Now these dfs are no stored in any location on the system, but these have been created and can be addressed if checked. Is there a way to iterate over these dataframes to run the same model for all of them? @W-B

Comment: @shweta24 using my second options , save them in dict

Comment: If I use second option, I need to save each df at a location and read it again as  the dfs are still stored in dict and should be extracted by calling out separately, is there a way to do this task using "locals" ?

Comment: @shweta24 It is hard to answer additional question via comment , please consider open a new topic . thanks

Comment: @W-B I have opened a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256818/iterating-over-several-dataframes-generated-using-locals
thanks!