# Iterating over several dataframes generated using "locals" : Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have split a dataframe "df" into smaller dataframes df1, df2...dfn such that all records with the same ID (from column "UNIT-ID") are grouped together and stored in those smaller dataframes.

```
Input:

UNIT-ID Q1  Q2  Q3
110-P1  37  487 0
110-P1  31  140 1
110-P1  46  214 1
110-P2  29  287 1
110-P2  45  131 1
110-P2  39  260 0
110-15  23  346 0
110-15  31  419 1
110-15  37  287 0
110-15  36  228 1
110-15  48  309 1

Output:
df1:        
 UNIT-ID    Q1  Q2  Q3
    110-P1  37  487 0
    110-P1  31  140 1
    110-P1  46  214 1

df2:            
 UNIT-ID    Q1  Q2  Q3
    110-P2  29  287 1
    110-P2  45  131 1
    110-P2  39  260 0
```

I have used the below code to achieve this, thanks to @W-B who answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284534/numbering-and-creating-dataframes-in-a-groupby-loop/53284614?noredirect=1#comment95310242_53284614).

```
variables = locals()
for i,j in enumerate(df.groupby('UNIT-ID')):
    variables["df{0}".format(i+1)] = j[1]
df1
Out[13]: 
   UNIT-ID  Q1   Q2  Q3
16  110-15  23  346   0
17  110-15  31  419   1
18  110-15  37  287   0
19  110-15  36  228   1
20  110-15  48  309   1
```

Next, I want to run few preprocessing steps and a Deep Learning model over each of these individual dataframes, Now, these dataffames - df1, df2.. dfn, are not stored in any location on the local drive, but these have been created and can be addressed if checked. Is there a way to iterate over these dataframes?

One may use "dict" to divide into df1, df2... dfn as follows, but using this option, I need to save each df at a physical location and read it again as the dfs are still stored in the dict and have to be extracted by calling out separately. is there a way to do this task using "locals" or any other technique?

```
d={"df{0}".format(i+1):j[1]for i,j in enumerate(df.groupby('UNIT-ID'))}
d['df1']
Out[17]: 
   UNIT-ID  Q1   Q2  Q3
16  110-15  23  346   0
17  110-15  31  419   1
18  110-15  37  287   0
19  110-15  36  228   1
20  110-15  48  309   1
```

Comment: You can apply a for loop in dict as well

Comment: could you help with an example?

Comment: You *should not have been dynamically creating variables in the first place*. You end up just manipulating the global namespace, which is literally a `dict` object. You should have used a `dict` from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like iterating through all your code variables, selecting by name the ones who are your "sub-dataframes" (for example, using a pattern in their names such as `subDf`) and them executing something just in those variables. To make my idea more clear, run the example below:

```
variables = locals()
for i,j in enumerate(df.groupby('UNIT-ID')):
    variables["subDf{0}".format(i+1)] = j[1]

for each in [v for k,v in variables.items() if 'subDf' in k]:
    print(v)

#output:
#   UNIT-ID  Q1   Q2  Q3
#6   110-15  23  346   0
#7   110-15  31  419   1
#8   110-15  37  287   0
#9   110-15  36  228   1
#10  110-15  48  309   1


#  UNIT-ID  Q1   Q2  Q3
#0  110-P1  37  487   0
#1  110-P1  31  140   1
#2  110-P1  46  214   1


#  UNIT-ID  Q1   Q2  Q3
#3  110-P2  29  287   1
#4  110-P2  45  131   1
#5  110-P2  39  260   0
```

This way, you can print all the subdataframes without having to save them elsewhere. Since I'm unsure what exactly you plan to do with your data, I can't tell if this is the best approach. But will definitely iterate through the dataframes you created!

Comment: This solution works for me. Thanks a lot, appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Just don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue ;)